# Modernizr tests/YepNope on Wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, modernizr, yepnope, browser-feature-detection

For the last few hours I've tried getting YepNope and some Modernizr tests working, but without any luck.

Modernizr is loaded in the head, jQuery, `plugins.js` and `script.js` at the bottom of the page (in that order). Nothing fancy, but handy because every resource called in `scripts.js` is  already available when executed. All scripts are loaded correctly, the test is the only scripting going on.

I want to test if need to load a polyfill for form validation, so this is the test: `Modernizr.formvalidationapi`. Of course I made sure that `Modernizr.addTest` and the `forms-validation` non-core detect is included in my build, together with HTML5 input types & attributes and `Modernizr.load`, which is basically `yepnope.js`

So in my `script.js`, there is the following:

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.formvalidationapi,  
  yep  : alert("yep"),
  nope : alert("nope")
});
```

I added the alerts just to debug of course.
I tested this in Safari 6.0.2 and Firefox 18.0.2, both times it alerts "yep", followed by "nope", so I assume there is an error somewhere.
I also tried to wrap the code in a document ready wrapper, which changed nothing.

As jQuery runs in no conflict mode inside Wordpress I believe ("$" can't be used, instead "jQuery" has to be used), I included this to remap the dollar sign to jQuery:

```
(function($){})(window.jQuery);
```

It also did nothing.

At the moment I believe it has something to do with Wordpress' own `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`, but I am not sure as I think it *is* possible to use Modernizr tests in a Wordpress site.

Where am I going wrong?

P.S.: I am aware that there is also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, but I posted my question here because I believe the problem lies inside my script and not Wordpress. If you wish, I can post the question there of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was just being stupid non-stop. Instead of `Modernizr.formvalidationapi` I have to test `Modernizr.formvalidation` to get everything working. What a waste of time that was, ha.